# MySql - Create table and intermediate table from existing table with data

Tags: mysql

I have a purchases table that stores all the items related to a purchase.  I'm reworking tables and such to better structure my table design and I believe I need a take my purchases table and convert it to purchases, transactions, and purchase_transactions (intermediate table).

An abbreviated illustration of my purchases table would be

```
columns related to the purchase item | columns related to the transaction
```

Each transaction can have multiple purchase items attached to it so there is a lot of redundant transaction information if a purchase has several items.  As well, when I process a refund or similar I have to overwrite the current transaction information so history is lost.

My question is, is there a way to write a script to break up my purchases table and not only carve out a transactions table, but to also create the purchase_transactions intermediate table and preserve all info?

I believe I can carve out the transactions table like so

```
CREATE TABLE transactions AS
  SELECT [ transaction_id, transaction_status_id...etc ]
  FROM purchases
```

But I'm lost as to how to include the intermediate table into this process if it's possible.

My alternative would be to create a php chunk function to go through all the records and create the entries, but there is a lot of data so that seems pretty inefficient.

Comment: A pivot table is something else entirely. What you are referring to is a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). However unless there is a many-to-many relationship on items and transactions, you only need 2 tables (storing the transaction_id in the items table).

Comment: There is a many to many relationship - transactions have many purchases (purchase items) and purchases can have many transactions (declined, approved, refunded).

Comment: @DigitalChris thank you for pointing out my wrong use of pivot - I've changed it to an intermediate table.

Comment: I think the way you have to do this is to loop over all records in the table. First, check if the purchase and/or transaction is already in your new table setup. If not, insert them. Then insert the junction record. Data integrity is your main concern. Efficiency not as much-- this is a one time procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to solve this myself as the purchases table held all the information needed for the transactions table and the purchase_transactions intermediary table.

I simply created my transactions table with an primary key id field and inserted the data I needed into that:

```
  INSERT INTO transactions (`client_id`, `last_four`, `transaction_id`,`transaction_status_id`, 
       `total`, `payment_type_id`,`cart_id`, `created_at`)
        SELECT `client_id`, `last_four`, `transaction_id`,`transaction_status_id`, 
        sum(`total`) as `total`, `payment_type_id`,`cart_id`, `created_at`
        FROM purchases
        GROUP BY `cart_id`
        ORDER BY `id` ASC")
```

And then I used the create table syntax below to create the purchase_transactions table.

```
 CREATE TABLE purchase_transactions
        SELECT `id`, `cart_id`
        FROM purchases
        ORDER BY id ASC
```

Lastly, I renamed the id column above purchase_id.  I'm not sure, but I'm thinking I could have just used as statement in the create table to:

```
  SELECT `id` as `purchase_id`
```